# H5T.copy: Failed to copy C_S1 with status -1

Tags: c#, hdf5

I am trying to create and fill an h5 file within the application I am working on. I need to use HDF5DotNet. When I try to create a string datatype, I get the following exception:

> H5T.copy: Failed to copy C_S1 with status -1

when I call `H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.C-S1)`.

I have no idea what it means and how this exception can occur. Any help would be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share more of your code to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The problem is, that when I try to reproduce this outside the application I cannot and everything looks OK. What I do is declare:
using HDF5DotNet

H5.open();
H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.C_S1)

going further, I would have to let you into the application I am developing and I cannot do that. I just wanted to know if anyone has encountered a problem like that and maybe advise what circumstances it might have occurred.

Comment: What I thought is if there is a problem in using directives. the Hdf5DotNet uses InteropServices and in the class the call fails specifically uses InteropServices as well.